# Get all files changed in a specific path and in all commits,

Tags: git

I need to get all files changed in a specific path, in all commits.

I know:

```
git log -- [path]
git show dee540c0 --name-only
```

How do I combine the two commands?

Comment: `git log` is actually enough if I understand your needs correctly, i.e. `git log --stat -- PATH` (or `git log --name-only -- PATH` if you are not interested in statistics) will show changes made in every commit to files in PATH.

Comment: Yes,
I need to compre 2 versions
so I want to have a list of all files I had changed ever.

Comment: Then probably you need something like `git diff --name-only $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD) -- PATH`

Comment: getting close,
now I realise that I retrive all files in path.
so I acutualy need to exclude the first commit .

Comment: Thanks,
I found a different way.
using Dir compare.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, I used MELD to compare path between vanila version and working Dir.

Comment: git diff commitId1 commitId2 is proper git solution. could be use with path too.